# Total number of currency transactions

Tags: fx

All of the Forex volume/transactions are always reported in total dollar amount.  I am interested in the number of individual trades.  Where can I find this?

Granularity doesn't matter, transactions/year would be small enough.  I would prefer to separate out by currency.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it suggests that the user is not a working quant.

Comment: I am definitely not, I am working on modeling for a related domain but this is a side-project at best.  I did not know there was such a rule, my apologies.  Delete away!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as total trading volume and especially no aggregate transactions.

The reason for that is that Foreign Exchange is a purely OTC (over the counter) market so even you see volume by one broker/ECN that is only volume that crosses the ECN or transactions at the particular broker. Nobody knows exactly how much volume is transacted during any given time period or on a given day/week/month/year.

Comment: I am only looking for a rough order-of-magnitude estimate, hundreds of thousands, millions, billions?.  Even multiplying a single large brokers number of trade would work.

Comment: Not sure how you derive value from such estimate. But I am unable to give you such figures because I never thought about it as I never expected such numbers add value